# How to check value of environment variable with string containing a space

Tags: windows, batch-file

(Disclaimer: I reviewed more than a dozen related SO questions prior to posting this question, but could not locate an answer.)

How do I check the value of a variable that contains a string with a space?

For example:

```
set str1=has space
if %str1%==has space echo Equal
```

Above produces the following error:

> space==has was unexpected at this time.

Adding double quotes around the string on the right hand side does not help.

I am using Command Prompt [Version 6.1.7601] on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
set str1=has space
if "%str1%"=="has space" echo Equal
```

Comment: Thank you!  (Knew it was going to be something simple.)

Comment: By the way, re: your edit of the question title: the variable in question is a simple one, not an environment variable.  Is such an ephemeral variable considered an environment variable for the duration of its life?

Comment: @Sabuncu: there is no such thing as a "DOS Variable" in Windows (because there is no such thing as "DOS" anymore). It's always an environment variable. The only difference between the ones you set in the control panel and those you set in a batch file is the lifetime of the variable. If you call a program from within your batch file it cannot tell if the variable is defined globally or just for this instance of `cmd.exe`.

Comment: I see, thanks.  Something I was wondering about all this time.